# NGRX Redux store -- selecting only a slice of the state returns 'undefined' even if intellisense autocompletes and everything in the model matches

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx-store, angular-redux

Using @ngrx-redux/store, the latest verson. I can select via string any slice of the state. When I try to access a property, it returns 'undefined' errors.

Syntax:

```
this.loadedClients = this.store.select(
      state => state.superUser.loadedClients
    );
```

using

`this.loadedClients = this.store.select('superUser')`

works, but using the async pipe to get loadedClients property causes messy markup.

I can't find examples on Google or in the documentation.

Comment: presented string selector doesn't pick the `loadedClients` subproperty. Have you tried `select('superUser', 'loadedClients')` ?

Comment: @Kos surprising enough, the presented selector does get that subproperty with that syntax.

I traced back the steps through the functions and turns out I forgot to return the state in one  of the reducers which always ran onInit in that specific component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was an issue inside my reducer messing up with that property -- it shouldn't have worked at all.